# Facebook's pages.isfan requires user id 

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Basically I would like to know if my visitor is already a fan of my Facebook Page or not.
I tried looking a while and `pages.isFan` is the best solution so far.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/pages.isFan/

But `pages.isFan` need user id (`uid`), which I can only get if they installed or grant access to my Facebook apps.

My question is, is there a way just to get the `uid` of my visiting user without ask them to grant access to my Facebook apps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code should do the trick:

```
$signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];
list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2);
$data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

if (empty($data["page"]["liked"])) {
  /* Not Fan */
}
else {
  /* Fan */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering me. i tried your code but $signed_request return null.

Comment: Ok, Make sure your tab URL in facebook integration is not missing www. and "/" at the end. Also check this post, your problem maybe in there: http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=91179

Comment: Thanks Soufiane, i'll try this tomorrow, it's too late here now. i'll keep it update here. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks Soufiane, i manage to get it working now. Thanks for you guidance.

Answer (score 0):

More methods can be found here: http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/facebook-api-check-if-a-user-is-fan-of-a-facebook-page/20/