# Is Fan of Facebook Page?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-page

Please take a look on this tab on this Facebook Page

http://www.facebook.com/HotelGuru.sk?sk=app_233066690095330

My question is how is it possible that the app on the tab knows if I liked a fan page, because when I like it, the tab changes its content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Signed Request](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) conatins `data` if the user is an `admin` of the page and/or a `liked` the page (which is akin to fan).

[Signed Request Facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/)

Similar question with the coding examples here [Facebook's pages.isfan requires user id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902868/facebook-pages-isfan-2question)

You didn't say what language you are using so I am intentionally leaving this quite vague as there is little point doing an example that is irrelevant.

EDIT: This page has some examples for server and client workflows, which are quite good http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/facebook-api-check-if-a-user-is-fan-of-a-facebook-page/20/

Comment: Thanks a lot! I know how it works now :) Sorry about that language thing :)