# Is website user a Facebook fan?

Tags: facebook

Can I find out if a user on my website has liked my Facebook page?  There is a previous stackoverflow question on this:

[Facebook's pages.isfan requires user id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902868/facebooks-pages-isfan-requires-user-id)

but it references a broken link.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution in the referenced SO question won't work based on your requirement. You phrased your question to check if a visitor likes a certain page on YOUR website. The linked question talks about this check inside a Facebook app.

To check if a user likes a page outside of FB, you would need [How to check if a user likes my Facebook Page or URL using Facebook's API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093398/how-to-check-if-a-user-likes-my-facebook-page-or-url-using-facebooks-api). The accepted answer shows the PHP solution, further down is a pure JavaScript solution.

Comment: That link seems to discuss how to make this check within a FB app.  I'm trying to figure out if this can be done on the order receipt page of my website so I can find out if the order which was just placed was placed by someone who has liked my FB page or not.